# Java CXF Error: A encryption username needs to be declared

Tags: java

I have a java web service client which has been compiled against a new version of a WSDL for a Service written in .NET WCF. When we try to execute the client to send a test request and response we encounter the error:

```
 Mar 28, 2017 3:30:10 PM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain 
 doDefaultLogging WARNING: Interceptor for 
 {http://EMVS.EU/20161/}ProductService#
 {http://EMVS.EU/20161/}ProcessProductServiceSubscription has thrown 
 exception, unwinding now
 org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: A encryption username needs to be 
 declared.
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AbstractBindingBuilder.policyNotAsserted(AbstractBindingBuilder.java:315)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AbstractBindingBuilder.setEncryptionUser(AbstractBindingBuilder.java:1643)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AsymmetricBindingHandler.doEncryption(AsymmetricBindingHandler.java:432)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AsymmetricBindingHandler.doEncryptBeforeSign(AsymmetricBindingHandler.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AsymmetricBindingHandler.handleBinding(AsymmetricBindingHandler.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:176)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:572)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:481)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:136)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.processProductServiceSubscription(Unknown Source)
    at DemoOrganisation.emvs.client.ProductServiceMAHTester.sendProcessProductServiceSubscriptionMessage(ProductServiceMAHTester.java:403)
    at DemoOrganisation.emvs.client.ProductServiceMAHClient.main(ProductServiceMAHClient.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:291)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It seems to be complaining about the following property in the clientdotnet.properties file:
mah.enc.alias=12345678901234567890

This points to our certificate in the key store for encrypting.

The existing properties work fine when we run a maven build to test the web service client with 2013 version of the WSDL contract. However it does not work with the regenerated classes from our latest version 2016!

I have tried to understand what property the message is looking for. According to the CXF documentation we can add the property of the encrypted username to the spring client xml as follows:

```
<jaxws:client name="{http://cxf.apache.org}MyPortName"
  createdFromAPI="true">
  <jaxws:properties>
     <entry key="security.callback-handler"
         value="interop.client.KeystorePasswordCallback"/>
     <entry key="security.signature.properties"
         value="etc/client.properties"/>
     <entry key="security.encryption.properties"
         value="etc/service.properties"/>
     <entry key="security.encryption.username"
         value="servicekeyalias"/>
  </jaxws:properties>
```

But when I look into our spring file I can only see:

```
<jaxws:client address="#{systemProperties['mah.epurl']}"
        name="{http://EMVS.EU/20161/}CustomBinding_IProductServiceMahV20161"
        createdFromAPI="true"/>
```

The properties are all defined in a file called:
clientDotNet.properties

Regards

Romeel

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely because you haven't set the following properties in the context for the port which creates the webservice client:

- ws-security.encryption.username
- ws-security.encryption.properties
- ws-security.username
- ws-security.password
- ws-security.signature.username
- ws-security.signature.properties
- ws-security.callback-handler

I ran into the same issue and I set the above properties and the client code for the webservice worked.